# Why does an empty while in Java not break when condition is set by other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

While trying to unit test a threaded class, I decided to use active waiting to control the behavior of the tested class. Using empty while statements for this failed to do what I intended. So my question is:

*Why does the first code not complete, but the second does?*

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555001/java-stuck-in-the-while-loop-in-the-background-thread), but it doesn't have a real answer nor an MCVE and is far more specific.

**Doesn't complete:**

```
public class ThreadWhileTesting {

    private static boolean wait = true;

    private static final Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {Thread.sleep(50);} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        wait = false;
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wait = true;
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        while (wait); // THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
    }
}
```

**Does complete:**

```
public class ThreadWhileTesting {

    private static boolean wait = true;

    private static final Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {Thread.sleep(50);} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        wait = false;
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wait = true;
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        while (wait) {
            System.out.println(wait); // THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that the empty while gets optimized by the Java compiler, but I am not sure. If this behavior is intended, how can I achieve what I want? (Yes, active waiting is intented since I cannot use [locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for this test.)

Comment: Because `wait` isn't volatile and the loop body is empty, so the thread has no reason to believe it will change. It is JIT'd to `if (wait) while (true);`.

Comment: As to how you can achieve what you want: Why not use a countdownlatch?

Comment: Reason why the second one completes: System.out.println is a synchronized method which, in your case, is enough to solve the visibility issue. Note that the program is not correctly synchronized and the second version may not complete on a different machine and/or JVM.

Comment: @Fildor, because I specifically need the thread to wait even when interrupted.

Comment: @nrohwer catch the interruption then, and go back to waiting for the countdown latch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wait` isn't volatile and the loop body is empty, so the thread has no reason to believe it will change. It is JIT'd to

```
if (wait) while (true);
```

which never completes if `wait` is initially true.

The simple solution is just to make `wait` `volatile`, which prevents JIT making this optimization.

---

As to why the second version works: `System.out.println` is internally synchronized; as described in the [JSR133 FAQ](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization):

> Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory.

so the `wait` variable will be re-read from main memory next time around the loop.

However, you don't actually guarantee that the *write* of the `wait` variable in the other thread is committed to main memory; so, as @assylias notes above, it might not work in all conditions. (Making the variable `volatile` fixes this also).

Comment: Could you also provide a link to where I can find out that JIT does in fact make this optimization? I always like it, if an answer allows me to learn more than asked for. :)

Comment: @nrohwer I can't find a specific link, but it's called "redundant load removal", or something like that.

Comment: @nrohwer The Java Language Specification (JLS) says that the compiler and/or the run-time system are _allowed_ to make that optimization.  (Open the JLS, and search for `volatile`.)  If you're writing code for any purpose other than one-time, personal use or experimentation, then that's all you need to know.

Comment: Thank you. This one really confused me. Could you recommend a resource about concurrency for beginners where I can learn such things?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that *both* of those examples are incorrect, but the second works because of an *implementation artifact* of the `System.out` stream.

A deeper explanation is that according to the JLS Memory Model, those two examples have a number of legal *execution traces* which give unexpected (to you) behavior.  The JLS explains it like this ([JLS 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)):

> A memory model describes, given a program and an execution trace of that program, whether the execution trace is a legal execution of the program. The Java programming language memory model works by examining each read in an execution trace and checking that the write observed by that read is valid according to certain rules.
>
> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.
>
> This provides a great deal of freedom for the implementor to perform a myriad of code transformations, including the reordering of actions and removal of unnecessary synchronization.

In your first example, you have one thread updating a variable and a second thread updating it with no form of synchronization between the tro threads.  To cut a (very) long story short, this means that the JLS does not guarantee that the memory update made by the writing thread will every be visible to the reading thread.  Indeed, the JLS text I quoted above means that the compiler is entitled to assume that the variable is never changed.  If you perform an analysis using the rules set out in JLS 17.4, an execution trace where the reading thread never sees the change is legal.

In the second example, the `println()` call is (probably) causing some serendipitous flushing of memory caches.  The result is that you are getting a different (but equally legal) execution trace, and the code "works".

The simple fix to make your examples both work is to declare the `wait` flag as `volatile`.  This means that there is a *happens-before* relationship between a write of the variable in one thread and a subsequent read in another thread.  That in turn means that in all legal execution traces, the result of the write will be visible to to the readin thread.

This is a drastically simplified version of what the JLS actually says.  If you really want to understand the technical details, they are all in the spec.  But be prepared for some hard work understanding the details.