# Why can't while(flag){} end

Tags: java, kotlin

code like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var flag = true
Thread {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("time over")
    flag = false
}.start()
while (flag) {
    Thread.sleep(100)
}
println("finish")
}
```

the run result is :

```
time over
finish
```

The program is over

if change to:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var flag = true
Thread {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("time over")
    flag = false
}.start()
while (flag) {
   //Do nothing
}
println("finish")
}
```

"finish" cannot be print,The program is stuck. Why is that?

Comment: try marking the flag as "@Volatile var flag = true"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are getting a cached version of your flag. Take a look at the volatile keyword.

Basically here you are updating the flag in one thread, but the other is still seeing is own cached version of the flag.

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 2 seconds for the same answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know the use of volatile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is first thread need time to set your flag is false but while loop execute before thread finish that means still your flag is true so that  its never get false. 
we need to set flow after thread finish then check while condition for that use thread sleep.

```
var flag = true
Thread {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("time over")
    flag = false
}.start()
Thread.sleep(3000)
while (flag) {

}

println("finish")
```

Comment: So why the "time over" is also not printing in 2nd case of OP?

Comment: println("time over") is printing but not printing "finish" in 2nd case

Answer (score 0):

When the variable flag is not declared `volatile`, the compiler sometimes (depends on the one used) optimises your while loop code to the following :

```
if (condition) {
    while (true) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Refer [this link](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/friends-optimizing-compilers-who-needs-enemies-volatile-variables-loop-invariants-and-thr/) for more. Here is a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635952/why-does-an-empty-while-in-java-not-break-when-condition-is-set-by-other-thread).

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know the use of volatile